# Introduce delay in the data emitted by socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have built socket connection, In which I have a graph in frontEnd. This graph gets updated based on input provided by the user. On the backend I'm emitting data( array of data sent to frontend ). Is it possible to introduce delay between each value of the array emmited by the socket?

I have tried putting the code inside setInterval function, but soon I realised my stupidity. I'm clueless on how to proceed.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`new connection id: ${socket.id}`);
    socket.emit('test event', 'data is getting generated');
    //sendData(socket);
    socket.on('test', data => {
        console.log("DATA ", data);
        let start = data.start_val;
        const arr = [];
        while (start <= data.end_val) {
            arr.push(start);
            start = start + data.interval;
        }
        model.data.create({
            startvalue: data.start_val,
            endvalue: data.end_val,
            difference: data.interval

        });
        socket.emit('response', arr);
    });

})
```

I'm sending 3 values to backend Start_val, end_val and difference. These values are used to generate data. For example - Input:- start_val = 10, end_val = 30, difference = 30. Then the array sent back is [10,20,30]. Now I want to understant if I can provide a time delay of 1 second between each value of the array. i.e 10 should come on the 1st second, 20 should arrive at 2nd second and so on. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about looping over the data and using a setTimeout function that increases its delay with each iteration:

```
for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        socket.emit('response', [arr[x]]);
    }, 1000 * (x+1));
}
```

You would have to send back only 1 number at a time. Here we would send back [10]... so on the client you would need to handle how that data is received and push it into the array that is used for the graph, or what ever is reading that data after its sent.

Another possibility is introducing this delay on the client side of this application.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply!!. Umm.. So I'm using chart.js on the client side. Basically it has has a data attribute which I'm equating to this emitted array. And yes, delaying it on the client side is another way but then again its a quick fix. I want to figure out how we can do it from the backend.

Comment: Try what I suggested. You can send back 1 number from that loop at a time, and on the client .on, just push the received data to the array thats being used by the chart. There should be a method to forcefully refresh the chart when you add more data to that array.  (I havent used chart.js in a while, so I cant really comment there).

Comment: Right, Let me change the code and I shall update you!!. Thanks again :)

Comment: Chart is getting refreshed each time new data is received, so for 10 it changes and shows only one bar and for next value new single bar, chart.js is updating the new values automatically with each incoming input.

Comment: Are you pushing to the array thats being read? So if the chart is reading arr = [], you should be pushing from the .on, arr.push(data) etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that only.

Comment: Best I can do is direct you to the chart.js docs on updating: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html - Otherwise I assume the backend is sending the delayed values as expected? Sorry I can't be of more assistance.

Comment: Not a problem!!. Thanks for helping me here. I'm upvoting your first solution, In any case that will be the logic for backend, I'll figure out the frontend logic. Thank you.

Comment: Tried to upvote but due to my new account I couldn't.

Comment: Hello!, So I eventually got my bar chart to render 1 bar at a time with a interval of 1 sec using your code. But something very weird is happening. Each time I insert new values I get that many bars coming together at a time. For example if I insert values second time, each bar comes twice. and If I Insert values third time each bar is coming thrice. It's a very weird behaviour and I cant seem to wrap my head around it